# Chart JS Poner 2 graficos en un modal

Tags: chart.js

Hola lo que quiero hacer es que en el mismo grafico de barras que mostrare, se pueda desmarcar y marcar la opción de torta, se puede? Desde ya, muchas gracias. Encontre que se puede hacer un mix entre barra y linea, pero no se puede con barra y torta con ese metodo. El metodo es este https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html .Si en vez de line pongo "pie" no me muestra nada
[image: Imagen]

```
type: "bar", // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
      data: {
        labels: ["Lectura", "Tarea", "Escritura"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Tiempos",
            data: [dataLecAv, dataTarAv, dataEscAv],
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(37, 179, 179, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
              "rgba(72, 161, 36, 0.6)",
              "rgba(37, 179, 179, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
              "rgba(72, 161, 36, 0.6)",
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "#777",
            hoverBorderWidth: 3,
            hoverBorderColor: "#000",
          },
        ],
```

Comment: Lo que entendi es, cuando te muestre el grafico exista la opcion de quitar ese de barra y poner uno diferente?? si es asi lo que tienes que hacer es tener un boton que al presionarlo este oculte el grafico actual y muestre el otro, el cual previamente lo tendras oculto

Comment: Claro, pero vi en este enlace https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html  que le agrega un type=line abajo del principal y se le genera el de linea tambien, eso es lo que quiero si es posible, no crear un boton aparte. Porque si creo un boton aparte tendria que abrir otro modal y yo lo que quiero es que se genere en el mismo

Comment: Normalmente cuando pasas mas de un dataset automaticamente te genera esa opcion, ahora, en tu caso segun lo que muestra la documentacion oficial te falta el segundo dataset solo tienes uno que es label: "Tiempos", tendrias que pasar un segundo dataset

Comment: Claro, pero no funciona. Si le paso otro dataset y le pongo type:line si funciona, pero si le pongo type:pie, no funciona